# Can I view the watchOS install history to see what version of watchOS I had before the current one?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update, apple-watch, watchos

I just recently updated my Apple Watch to watchOS version 8.7. Long back story, but I'd like to know which version of watchOS I was running before that. Is there any way to find that information on the phone or watch?

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer, but not one that would work for everyone.

It seems pieces of health data have metadata associated with them including the watchOS version used when that data was recorded. Using the Health app, I was able to see which version of watchOS I was using before the update.

This solved my issue, so I thought I would update.

Comment: It might help others to outline the steps you took to discover the relevant data in the Health app. At present your answer could be updated to make it clearer.

Comment: Any regularly recorded health data, like heart rate or steps. You go to the page for that data and click to view all data. Each record has a version attached.